# Вставить координаты через js в td

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день, у меня есть таблица

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

с помощью js хочу вставить внутрь каждой td его координаты, вот мои старания=)

```
var d = document,
       td = d.getElementsByTagName('td'),
       input = document.createElement('input');
       Object.keys(td).map( function(item) {
            var coordinates = td[item].getBoundingClientRect();
            item.outerHTML = coordinates.left + coordinates.top + coordinates.right + coordinates.bottom;
       })
```

Но outerHTML и innerHTML не работает,спасибо.

Comment: а как именно не работает? по коду могу предположить, что вывелось одно значение вместо 4

Comment: ну ничего не добавляет и ошибки не пишет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не `item.outerHTML =`, a `td[item].innerText =`.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, **куда** шла попытка вставить.

`Object.keys` возвращает **массив ключей**, поэтому *item* передаваемый в callback функции *map* - это ключ: 1,2,3... и т.д. обычная строка, а у строки нет свойства *innerHTML*, и при присваивании его ничего не происходит.

Для решения, можно брать *td[item]*, либо воспользоваться другой функцией для пробегания по коллекции:

```js
var d = document,
  tds = d.getElementsByTagName('td'),
  input = document.createElement('input');
[].forEach.call(tds, function(item) {
  var coordinates = item.getBoundingClientRect();
  item.innerHTML = `left=${coordinates.left}; top=${coordinates.top}; right=${coordinates.right}; bottom=${coordinates.bottom}`;
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Нашел ошибку через js
d[item].innerHTML = coordinates.left + coordinates.top + coordinates.right + coordinates.bottom;

Comment: @AleksandrKar, обрати внимание, что значения полей объекта _coordinates_ - это числа, а не строки, поэтому сложив их ты получишь _одно число_, а не строку со всеми четырьмя